# Quitar subrayado de link en una imagen

Tags: html, css, enlace

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola quisiera saber como quitar el subrayado del los links, probe con el tex decoration: none; y no me funciono.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: Eso añade un resaltado, no quita el subrayado violeta

Comment: Prueba editando la pregunta y anexando tu codigo para que podamos ayudarte mas fácil

Comment: Prueba a añadirle `text-decoration: none;` a tu etiqueta `<a>` en la que tienes tus iconos

Comment: el segundo párrafo del enlace te marca el orden `a, a:visited, a:link, a:hover, a:active {text-decoration:none;}`